# Super-simple updates app in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, content-management-system, crud

I have to cook up a super-simple Rails app with the following functionality:

Only one model: Update. Updates are simply news that my client will be publishing on the site, i.e. basically mini blog posts. An update has three fields: headline, text (both mandatory) and image.

The client will need to log in to create, update, & delete updates. No roles and authorization levels are necessary — just a single login / password combination for the above tasks.

It's desirable to have a very basic WYSIWYG (for inserting links, etc) in the UI for creating & editing updates.

It's been a while I've done something similar, so the question is: is it advisable just to roll everything from scratch or are there gems I should consider?

(I'll be probably using AWS and CarrierWave for images).

Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve this (and yes, it will be relatively simple) will be to use the [`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem with [`InheritedResources`](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources). Here's how:

---

**Flow**

Firstly, you'll want to ensure you're able to give the use a place to compose & submit the updates. To do this, you'll want to create a [simple backend (admin) system](http://www.iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1), to give you a separate space to update your backend:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   resources :updates, path: "", except: :show #-> domain.com/admin/
end

root: "updates#index"
resources :updates, path: "", only: [:show, :index] #-> domain.com/:id
```

The importance of this type of system is relevant.

The issue I think you're alluding to is the way in which you won't be able to either create or access the various mini-updates from a "protected" area. Using the method I'm detailing will only only provide this area, but also give you the ability to store the data correctly.

--

**Controller**

To get this to work, you'll need *two* controllers:

```
#app/controllers/updates_controller.rb #-> for general users
class UpdatesController < InheritedResources::Base
   #InheritedResources will create relevant CRUD resources
end

#app/controllers/admin/updates_controller.rb #-> for admin
class Admin::UpdatesController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user! #-> for Devise
  #InheritedResources creates relevant responses
end
```

The above two controllers are really the core of what you need. They provide the CRUD functionality for both the `admin` and `general areas of your app - giving you the ability to provide the users with the ability to upload as they require.

The biggest thing you need to consider is the *authentication*. This is handled with Devise (which I'll explain below). The thing you need to consider is the [`authenticate_user!`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) call - this is what determines whether the user is able to invoke the methods, depending on whether they are logged in (maintain an active session) or not

--

**Devise** (authentication)

The `Devise` gem will be what you need to get the authentication of your app sorted. This is what you're asking about -- and simply, it's a job for Devise.

There is a [great tutorial on how to handle this here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise):

[image]

The bottom line with Devise is that you need 3 things to get it working:

> 1. A `User` model
> 2. A `users` table
> 3. The Devise columns & system installed

Without over-burdening you, I'd just recommend using the controllers I put up above (with the corresponding views), the routes, and then Devise

Comment: Thanks for that Rich, so basically I will need a User model (and table) for authorization even though there's only one real-world user?

Comment: By the way, Inherited Resources is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a gem, but you could look at Rails Composer: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer - they have templates for generating apps that meet your needs. It lets you set options to help you customise them further.